# MongoDB via Mongoose JS - findByID res out of funktion

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want to use a findbyID.
My Code:

`db.findById(id, function(err, res) {});`

So i get from the function res clear data so i want to use them in a other function:

```
db.findById(id, function(err, res) {//some code});


router.get('/getdata', req, res) =>
  res.render('site', {
    data: [response from findById]
  })
);
```

So i need the responde from the function but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
router.get('/getdata', req, res) => {
  db.findById(id, function(err, result) {
    res.render('site', {
      data: result
    });
  });
});
```